# Liter/100 km or km/liter, which one is used in Japan?

Tags: usage, daily-life

In America we say the fuel economy of car as miles/gallon (miles per gallon). I know in some countries people use Liter/100 km (liter per 100 km). Some countries use km/Liter (km per liter).

Which format do Japanese people use, L/100 km or km/L?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use kilometers per liter only.

Answer (score 9):

That would be km/L (only).

[image: 燃費]
<sub>(source: [車ラボ.com](http://xn--zdkza0666d.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/abb3c303622f03654433809fdad5ac83.jpg))</sub>

Fuel efficiency is called 燃費 and "fuel efficient" or "fuel inefficient" are called 燃費がいい or 燃費が悪い.